# Entity Framework, adding table to existing context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

After following the steps for mapping an existing table to a model, I realized the table had some dependencies.

For the last three times that helped, I just droped the whole DBContext and started again.

I would like to just update my context for accommodate another table, which relates to the current ones.

My current context is:

```
public partial class CompanyContext : DbContext
{
    public CompanyContext() : base("name=CompanyContext")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<company> companies { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<company>()
            .Property(e => e.name)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<company>()
            .Property(e => e.symbol)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<company>()
            .Property(e => e.address)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<company>()
            .Property(e => e.zipcode)
            .IsFixedLength()
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<company>()
            .Property(e => e.cnpj)
            .IsFixedLength()
            .IsUnicode(false);
    }
}
```

A company's record has `id_city` which is not even appearing in the `DbContext`. But it is there in the model:

```
[Table("company")]
public partial class company
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(70)]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [StringLength(10)]
    public string symbol { get; set; }

    [StringLength(80)]
    public string address { get; set; }

    [StringLength(8)]
    public string zipcode { get; set; }

    public int id_city { get; set; }

    public int id_segment { get; set; }

    [StringLength(14)]
    public string cnpj { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    public DateTime? open_date { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to add the table `cities` to this context, what should I do? Is there any wizard for helping it?

I thought it could be just add something like:

```
public virtual DbSet<city> cities { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<city>()
        .Property(e => e.name)
        .IsUnicode(false);
}
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Which version of EF are you using ? EF6 or EF7 ?

Comment: I am using version 5, does it matter? I mean, has this behavior changed accross versions?

Comment: No, there is no wizzard. There's a thing called EntityFramework Reverse POCO Generator, but what you did should be enough. What's the problem? "It doesn't work." isn't really informative.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't know exactly what happened. Before it was just passing by, without returning any records, now it is. I am sorry, don't know what has changed actually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding property like

```
public virtual DbSet<company> companies { get; set; }
```

To the context tells EF that you have a table that will hold records of type `company`. This one line is enough and table will use standard mapping so table name will be `companies`.

You need to do the same for cities.

```
public virtual DbSet<city> cities { get; set; }
```

You also need to add virtual property `City` to the company class if you want to have relationship in the database and remove `id_city` field. If you want id of related city to be exposed explicitly on the `company` class , you have to either use naming convention that EF follows, ie name it `cityId` or add fluent mapping for it.

Comment: I am giving it a try again

Comment: Following your approach I got a proper error which helped me to figure out what was happening: `The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Byte' type to the 'System.Int32' type is not valid.` It was not blowing up before.

Comment: I mean, I thought I had made this before, but it was not returning any records, now I just made again, following your procedure, with lead to the same code (I guess) and it worked, sorry, don't know what I have done before